# Issues with PlayerPrefs in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, huawei-mobile-services

I developed a game with some PlayerPrefs included like HighScore, Username etc... after I tested it for iOS and Samsung, I published it into the App Stores. Everything seemed to be working fine, but then a friend of mine downloaded my game on an old Nokia device and also, someone downloaded it on a Huawei. They told me that in my game are bugs and I tried to figure out what this caused.

I found out that on "mainstream" devices like *iPhone* and *Samsung Galaxy* everything is working completely properly!

And after going through my scripts again, it was obviously that the PlayerPrefs didn't work right on those devices I have mentioned.

**So my Question is:**
Are there some devices that **CANNOT** save data on the device?
And if yes, how can I find out which they are?

Comment: How do you save and load the file?

Comment: You need to be very careful with your testing process. There are many mobile devices (also tablets, ipads etc) and you need to test on a bigger set than just 2. Each device has a slightly different credentials and access to file directory. There are tools to perform tests and I think that Unity has some test environment as well. Think about it,

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But do you think or know, if there are any devices, that are unsupported for playerPrefs?

Comment: On which exact nokia and huawei model does it not work? Also which Android OS version do they have? Which Unity version are you using?

Comment: devices who failed: Nokia 3.1 and huawei p10. My Unity version is 2018.2.13f1.